# Is this a flaw in JavaScript's prototypical inheritance model?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal

I've been learning prototypical inheritance in JavaScript from John Resig's *Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja*, and I was wondering what happens in the following code example (that I just made up).

```
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello World");
}

function Ninja() {}

Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
    alert("I can swing my sword.");
}

Ninja.prototype = new Person();

var ninja1 = new Ninja();
```

As far as I know, the result of all of these lines of code is that the variable `ninja1` references a `Ninja` object, that through its prototype, has the `swingSword` method, and through prototypical inheritance of `Person`'s prototype, has the `sayHello` method.

Where I am confused is in the following: since the property `swingSword` (which happens to be a method) was attached to `Ninja`'s prototype *before* a person instance was assigned to `Ninja`'s prototype, wouldn't the `swingSword` property/method be overwritten by the later assignment of the `Person` instance? If not, how can `Ninja`'s prototype property, which references the prototype object, reference both the `Person` instance, *and* have a `swingSword` property?

Comment: Did you run the code? What makes you think `ninja1` has both `sayHello` and `swingSword`?

Comment: The prototype of Ninja is completely overwritten when you do `Ninja.prototype = new Person();`. And `ninja1` won't have a swingSword method at the end of this. This is not the way to do prototypical inheritance.

Comment: For inheritance that do not force you to create an in instace of it's parent (new Person) you can use `Ninja.prototype=Object.create(Person.prototype);` or a helper function. More on constructor functions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 You're not using instance specific members but if you do you should do `Person.call(this);` in the Ninja constructor body (see the link).

Comment: if prototypical inheritance, (as upose to mimcing class inheritance with capital letter in function name, constructors and new), is truly important to you, then ditch that book.  just because functions use prototype as a key word for function usage, doesn't mean you have your hand fully in the glove of managing prototypes of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] that through its prototype, has the `swingSword` method, [...]

While the rest of that statement is correct -- that `ninja1` references `Ninja` (well, technically, `Ninja.prototype`) and will have a `sayHello` through inheritance -- your later thoughts are correct regarding `swingSword`.

> wouldn't the `swingSword` property/method be overwritten by the later assignment of the `Person` instance?

At the end of your snippet, `ninja1.swingSword` should be `undefined`.

```
console.log(typeof ninja1.swingSword); // 'undefined'

// as is:
console.log(typeof Ninja.prototype.swingSword); // 'undefined'
```

After `Ninja.prototype = ...`, the original `prototype` object that `swingSword` was attached to is no longer being referenced. So, it won't be used when creating new instances.

---

If you intend to *set* a new `prototype` object, you'll want make sure that's done before modifying it.

```
Ninja.prototype = new Person();

Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
    alert("I can swing my sword.");
}

var ninja1 = new Ninja();

console.log(typeof ninja1.swingSword); // 'function'
```

---

And, if `ninja1` actually does have a `swingSword`, it probably means that it was created before the `prototype` was changed.

Objects retain their own [`[[Prototype]]` reference](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) from when they were created regardless of what changes may be made to their constructor's `prototype` property.

```
Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
    alert("I can swing my sword.");
}

var ninja1 = new Ninja();

Ninja.prototype = new Person(); // won't affect existing instances

var ninja2 = new Ninja();

console.log(typeof ninja1.swingSword); // function
console.log(typeof ninja2.swingSword); // undefined
```

---

Example of each: http://jsfiddle.net/G8uTk/